# Creating a new user with SQL on PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

For a school project we have to develop a simple database that allows different users to have certain privileges over the database.  Anyway I have been struggling with the creation part, we were giving an example of code that can be used to create users and assign them to a database, however, it is not working.

```
 SELECT Host, User from mysql.user;

CREATE USER ‘David’ @‘localhost’ IDENTIFIED BY ‘password’;
SELECT Host, User from mysql.user;
Show databases;
Create database mydatabase;
Use mydatabase;
grant all on mydatabase.*to ‘David’ @‘localhost’;
set password for ‘David’ @‘localhost’ = password (‘newpassword’);
```

I do not know what is going on and how this actually works.  I have PHPmyAdmin, SQL and Apache running on the server.  Sorry if this question seems vague (or too simple )but it has been bothering me for a few hours now.  Is it a mistake in the code?

NOTE* LOCALHOST is my connection and this code is just an example

Comment: CREATE USER ‘David’ @‘localhost’ IDENTIFIED BY ‘password’; creates your database user grant all on mydatabase.*to ‘David’ @‘localhost’; grants it "all" permits, Lastly set password for ‘David’ @‘localhost’ = password (‘newpassword’); gives it a password, just do the same each line next to the previous one, don't create database twice or any of that.

Comment: I tried that, its still coming up with an error on the first line

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: CREATE USER ‘David’ @‘localhost’ IDENTIFIED BY ‘password’
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '‘password’' at line 1

Comment: try the same command but without a blank space between 'David' and @

Comment: yeah. getting the same error as before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use use ' not ‘ in your query.

```
SELECT Host, User from mysql.user;
CREATE USER 'David'@'localhost' identified by 'password';
SELECT Host, User from mysql.user;
Show databases;
Create database mydatabase;
Use mydatabase;
grant all on mydatabase.* to 'David'@'localhost';
flush privileges;
```

The problem is the quotation mark and spaces. Why are you changing the password after you created the user? You don't need to do that. Only flush user privileges.

Comment: Yeah thanks it works! I don't know about the password thing, this was just a code example of what my teacher gave me.  thank you very much!